# How to push all the nodes of Binary Tree into a stack and then print stack content?

Tags: c++, stl, stack, binary-tree

This is my attempt to do the same, but I'm getting a "bad_alloc" error.

```
stack<int>st;
void func(Node * root){
    
    if(root==NULL){
        return;
    }
    
    while(root!=NULL)
    {
        func(root->left);
        st.push(root->data);
        func(root->right);
    }

    //Printing stack data
    while (!st.empty()) 
    { 
        cout << '\t' << st.top(); 
        st.pop(); 
    } 
    cout << '\n'; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Root node passed as argument in func().

Comment: Could you explain the first while loop to me? I do not see when root will be set to NULL.

Comment: It's actually wrong. See the other answers for the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are using while loop and recursion both, though there is no need of the loop. You can use inorder/postorder/preorder traversal and push the elements into the stack. Here is my implementation:

```
void inorder(Node* root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(root->left);  // Call for left subtree
    st.push(root->data);  // Push the element to the stack 
    inorder(root->right); // Call for right subtree
    
}
```

Then simply print the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(root!=NULL)
{
    func(root->left);
    st.push(root->data);
    func(root->right);
}
```

This makes the program to go in infinite loop. `root` will be never null. You could change this to `if(root!=NULL)` to achieve what you are trying for, but that check is not needed as well since the `NULL` check is done prior to that.